# angular.js Error: factory.function(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this duplicate but doesn't matches with anyone that's why I have posted this one. I have one controller and one factory. Factory is working fine and getting response in console but when i called a function of factory a error has been printed. Please check below code:
Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('rsplApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookies',  'ngResource',  'ngSanitize', 'ngValidate']);
app.controller('AddProjectController',['$scope', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$location','Technologies', function ($scope, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, Technologies){        
        Technologies.loadTech().then(function(techRes){ 
        $scope.choices = techRes;//console.log(techRes);
        })
}])
```

Factory:

```
app.factory("Technologies",function($http){ 
var TechCat = {};   
TechCat.loadTech = function(){          
        $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'api/v1/technologies.php',
                    data    : '',  // pass in data as strings       
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                }).success(function(response){
                        //console.log(response);
                        return response;
                    }).error(function(erronrmsg){
                        return erronrmsg;               

                        })  

}

return TechCat;
})
```

now when i refresh page I received this error:
"Error: Technologies.loadTech(...) is undefined
@http://localhost/vk-angular/scripts/controllers/AddProjectController.js:4:4"

Comment: Correct your indenting and add semicolons for a start.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('rsplApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookies',  'ngResource',  'ngSanitize', 'ngValidate']);
app.controller('AddProjectController',['$scope', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$location','Technologies', function ($scope, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, Technologies){        
        Technologies.loadTech().then(function(techRes){ 
        $scope.choices = techRes;//console.log(techRes);
        })
}]);

app.factory("Technologies",function($http){ 
var TechCat = {};   
TechCat.loadTech = function(){          
      return  $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'api/v1/technologies.php',
                    data    : '',  // pass in data as strings       
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                }).success(function(response){
                        //console.log(response);
                        return response;
                    }).error(function(erronrmsg){
                        return erronrmsg;               

                        })  

};

return TechCat;
});
```

Comment: I think semi colon ; miss at service obj function, and return $http then only you will get promise, means you can use 'then' function inside controller

Comment: thankyou @saikumar you are right i have missed semi colon at service obj function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the $http promise from the `loadTech()` function. So, implicitly `undefined` is returned. But in your controller you are using `loadTech()` as if it returned a promise.